# Could 'orado' be used in reference to gold?

Tags: gramática, concordancia-gramatical

I'm trying to "backronym" a name from a set of letters/initials and I'd like to use 'orado' being a reference to gold, albeit informal, á la 'dorado' tho lacking the 'd' (de + oro + -ado). Could it be done? Would any native speaker use it so? Of course, 'orado' is the past participle of 'orar,' 'to pray,' which also has a nice connotation, but not quite what I'd like.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

There are really only two adjectives that refer to gold: *dorado* and *áureo*. The former means either “golden” or “gold-plated”, then latter is more general “(made) of gold” or “gold-like”. (*Dorar* means “to cover with gold, to apply gold plating” but also “to toast (bread), to brown”, so careful.)

*Orado* only brings to mind the verb *orar*, which in itself is not that common (most people use *rezar* instead); moreover, *orado* is only ever used as the participle of the verb in compound tenses. It never functions as an adjective, nor can it be used by itself in absolute participial constructions.¹ So *orado* wouldn't call up any associations at all.

---

¹ An absolute participial construction is something like “All things considered...” or “Come winter...”.

Comment: The meaning of "to toast" or "to brown" is related to the expression "golden brown" in English.